# Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_*_key

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

When doing this check:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -t
```

Getting:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

But when doing same check with `sudo` all is good:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t
$
```

Does anyone know why does this happen, what’s wrong with my standard user and how to fix it?

Comment: When you are getting the error, are you running sshd as root?

Comment: No as it's posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know why does this happen, what’s wrong with my standard
>   user and how to fix it?

There is nothing wrong; you are attempting to run `sshd` (SSH daemon) as a non-privileged user.

For example, I am on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and get the same exact “error” when running `/usr/sbin/sshd -t`:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Which is to be expected since `sshd` is the SSH *daemon*—note the `d` after `ssh`—that would run as a SSH server on the system listening and waiting for remote SSH login requests. So it would *always* need root/`sudo` permissions to work.

So this is not an “error” but rather expected behavior when attempting to run a system daemon like `sshd` as a non-privileged user.

Perhaps you are trying to run `ssh -t`? As the man page for the `ssh` `-t` option explains:

> Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary
>   screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
>   e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty
>   allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Which basically allows you to run a command remotely from your current terminal and have the output displayed locally as if it ran on your local machine. So—[as this page explains](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/16747.html)—if you wanted to run `ls` on a remote machine without actually fully logging in you could run this command:

```
ssh -t [username]@[hostname] ls
```

The output of `ls` would show up on your screen and the `ssh` connection would close immediately after that command completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the missing keys by running:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```

See also: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165382